# integral derivation?

Tags: integration

i have a problem in the partial derivatives of this function :

so consider this integral :

$u(x,t)=\int_0^t(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi_n(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)dy)ds$

can somone tell me why we have this equality :

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=\int_0^t(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi_n(y,s)\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x-y,t-s)dy)ds+\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(y,t)f(x-y,0)dy$

$x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ , $s,t$ are real >0

is there any "chain rule" ?

(here every functions are smooth and $f$ with compact support)

thank you very much !

Comment: [Leibniz's Rule for differentiating under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: @ Dr. MV thank you , i am  trying, but here is more complicated, i see !!

Comment: because the funcion inside the integral has 3 variables

Comment: Since you are only taking the derivative with respect to t, you can ignore those "other" variables.